# How to insert a space between Chinese character and English character?

Tags: regex, raku

I have a statement where Chinese character and English character are next to each other:

```
我Love Perl 6哈哈
```

I want to insert a space between Chinese character and English character:

```
我 Love Perl 6 哈哈
```

I search that `\u4e00-\u9fa5` represent Chinese character:

```
'哈' ~~ /<[\u4e00..\u9fa5]>/
```

but this result in:

```
Potential difficulties:
Repeated character (0) unexpectedly found in character class
at line 2
------> '哈' ~~ /<[\u4e00..\⏏u9fa5]>/
```

so how to match a Chinese character?

Comment: `/<[\u4e00..\u9fa5]>/` is the same as `/<[..00459\a\efuu]>/` or `/<[a0049f.euu\5\.]>/`

Comment: Wouldn't matching on the Script property be better?  Not actually sure we can, actually.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The main problem is that `\u` is not a valid escape.

```
> "\u4e00"
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Unrecognized backslash sequence: '\u'
------> "\⏏u4e00"
```

`\x` is though.

```
> "\x4e00"
一
```

At any rate, the character class you are trying to use doesn't cover all Chinese characters.

```
> '㒠' ~~  /<[\x4e00..\x9fa5]>/ 
Nil
```

What you probably want is to match on a script.

```
> '㒠' ~~  /<:Han>/
｢㒠｣
```

This has the benefit that you don't have to keep changing your character class every time a new set of characters gets added to Unicode.

---

At any rate you could do any of the following

```perl6
# store in $0 and $1
say S/(<:Han>)(<:Latin>)/$0 $1/ given '我Love Perl 6哈哈'
say S{(<:Han>)(<:Latin>)} = "$0 $1" given '我Love Perl 6哈哈'
# same with subst
say '我Love Perl 6哈哈'.subst: /(<:Han>)(<:Latin>)/, {"$0 $1"}

# only match between the two
say S/<:Han> <( )> <:Latin>/ / given '我Love Perl 6哈哈'
say S{<:Han> <( )> <:Latin>} = ' ' given '我Love Perl 6哈哈'
```

To change the value in a variable use `s///` or `.=subst`

```perl6
my $v = '我Love Perl 6哈哈';

$v ~~ s/(<:Han>)(<:Latin>)/$0 $1/;
$v ~~ s{(<:Han>)(<:Latin>)} = "$0 $1";
$v ~~ s/<:Han> <()> <:Latin>/ /;

$v .= subst: /(<:Han>)(<:Latin>)/, {"$0 $1"};
$v .= subst: /<:Han> <()> <:Latin>/,' ';
```

Note that `<(` causes everything to be ignored before it, and `)>` does the same for everything after it. (can be used individually).

You may want to use an inverted match instead for the character that is following.

```perl6
S/<:Han> <( )> [ <!:Han> & <!space> ]/ /
```

(Match a character that is at the same time not *Han* and not a *space*.)

Comment: perl6 -e 'say "我Love Perl 6哈哈".subst(/(<:Han>)(<:Latin>)/, {"$0 $1"})' -- prints -- "我 Love Perl 6哈哈".  Only some familiarity with topic areas.

Comment: @mr_ron It can be simplified if you used `<(` and `)>`